# SSRS remove white space from text boxes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to test for white space in SSRS? I have some text boxes that the user can type some text into. It is leaving some white spaces sometimes and I have some conditions that test for the length of the string. I wonder if there's an easy way to test for that. tabs, spaces etc.

the text that I get contains HTML markup that I get from the user using and HTML editor. This text can contain HTML tags and sometimes whitespaces between them. I have some ReExp that gets rid of all the HTML tags but it leaves behind the white spaces that might be there. I want to remove them too

Ex.

```
"<p> </p><br/>"
```

Result after the RegEx processing

```
" "
```

Comment: where are these text boxes? are they parameters?

Comment: I'm getting the value from the DB. I have a query in my report that gets their values.

Comment: but are they parameters? can you post an example, its hard to understand what you want

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to see exactly what you're trying to accomplish. I'm assuming you're trying to get rid of *excess* (but not all) space characters.

**Option 1: Regex**
Do it in the regular expression. If you're using regexes to strip the tags, why not fix whitespace issues there as well? Remember though, people who try to solve one problem with regexes [often end up with two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) ;-)

**Option 2: Expressions**
Use the [Visual Basic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c157t28f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in an expression when rendering a value in a textbox. Specifically [trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) come to mind. Something along these lines:

```
=Trim(Replace(Fields!SomFieldName.Value, "  ", " "))
'                    number of spaces >>  02    1
```

This can also be done in the query with SQL, I suppose.

**Option 3: Placeholder + HTML**
Use a placeholder and actually just render the html in the report. See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967%28SQL.105%29.aspx) for info. I'm not sure which html tags are supported though.